# How to add ViewModel implementation in build.gradle.kts for IntelliJ IDEA project?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, viewmodel, jetbrains-compose

Android Studio as default has access to ViewModel class `import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel`.
How can I use this ViewModel into IntelliJ IDEA Kotlin desktop project (compose for desktop).
developer.android.com provide guide how to add the dependices just for Android Studio project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class is android specific so can't be used for Compose for Desktop.

Comment: May be there some specific analog for CfD? I can't find the way to make global access to mutableState variables. Now all code contains in main function, but if I want to separate it to a diffirent functions I need make class or object with mutableState variables to provide access to them from all that functions. The problem is mutableState variables available only in @Compose function context or lambda's.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with an object, used state flows, then called collectAsState() on those flows.